# How to remove ASCII codes from text via notepad/Sublime or Excel

Tags: php, sql

I am having big trouble with ASCII commas and Quotations marks as they are causing error in DB importing.

Whenever I add text from website, it copies its ASCII codes also.

Example:

## (`“`)

This quotation mark is different from this

## (`"`)

(`“`) <--This quotation mark is an ASCII character which causing error in DB importing and every time that I need to check and replace it with default quotation mark (`"`)

Any idea please?

Comment: Can you give us a sample input? ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method #1**

You can do It with *Notepad++*.

1. Open file which you want to replace
2. Click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
3. In field `Find what:` type `“`
4. In field `Replace with:` type normal quotation mark `"`
5. Click `Replace all` button.

   ---

**Method #2**

You can use `[^\x00-\x7F]+` expression.

1. Open *Notepad ++*
2. Click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
3. Select `Regular Expression`
4. In `Find what:` field paste `[^\x00-\x7F]+`
5. Click `Find next`

It will find all non ASCII characters. So you can easy to delete / replace them.

---

**Method #3**

1. Open `Notepat++`
2. Click `Search`
3. Click `Find characters in range...`
4. Select `Non-ASCII Characters (128-255)`
5. Click `Find`

Working like method #2.

Comment: i know, But is there any way or program that exclude ASII symbols? like when you open source of website, it exclude ASII Symbols with their codes.

Comment: Hmmm, title of your questions telling that you are looking way how to remove It with using notepad. `How to remove ASII codes from text via notepad or excel` That's why I posted this solution.

Comment: Yes, But i need to know is there any way in these programs which dont allow ASII sybmobs to paste?

Comment: Updated my answer with 3rd method for *Notepad++*

Answer (score 0):

Never trust the users input is a good way to go. If its a trusted user copying and pasting or an unknown user filling out your forms.

You should always sanitise your input. ALWAYS.

Something like

```
function sanitise($input, $arguments = array()) {
    $input = htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE);

    if(array_key_exists('STRIP_TAGS') {
        $input = strip_tags($input);
    }

    //..etc
    return $input;
}
```

Pass in the options you wish to pass (there may be times you just want to strip  tags for instance but leave .

But in the end, filter all data and don't rely on your user remembering to do it for you.

If you are using a version of PHP prior to PHP 5.4 you could swap the htmlspecialchars with a preg_replace and match the corresponding ascii code with a quote.

```
$input = preg_replace('/[\x132]/', '"', $input);
```